# Optional add_subdirectory (like find_package)

Tags: cmake, git-submodules

In a project I have an external dependency (a library). This is optional but unlikely to be on the system already and may change a lot

So what I did was `find_package` the library and if it wasn't found (including the specific version) I download it from Github and call `add_subdirectory` on it (the download makes sure, the version is correct)

However this may fail due to unmet dependencies of that library which fails the whole build.

Is there a ways to try including the subdirectory and catching the failure w/o failing the build?

Note: The failure comes from a `find_package(...REQUIRED)` in the submodule.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify subpackage's CMakeLists.txt to check if it is being built as part of another project and then handle its unmet dependencies gracefully.

To check for that use

```
if( CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR STREQUAL CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR )
  # standalone build
else()
  # build as subdirectory of main project
endif()
```

To return early try [return()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/return.html).

If you can't alter subpackage, the only way I see is to check for all its dependencies in the main CMakeLists.txt and only if all of them are fulfilled, call `add_subdirectory()`.

Comment: This was also what I'm thinking. This trick is indeed very useful and already used for tests. But yes, I can't change the dependency and looking for all its dependencies is impractical. If there is no other solution I'll go with adding that as an option (if option is set, include/require the dependency)